Need to explain runtime error in this case
when I used sentence like this
high[last_candle-1] 

give me runtime error , and this means to check about candle after , may in pine script could not to do this but should be normal when we searching in last candles , that candles has been created and completed .
I need explanation barssince function , how it works , it should return refernce number for a last candle that condtion is true , Am I right ?

With the information you provided, it’s difficult to answer your question.  You ask about the barssince function, but your code doesn't have ta.barssince
